# When to use 'raw' attribute in http-requests

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I want to write a primitive script for downloading videos from youtube. As I understand I can get a binary content using 'content' attribute. It's written in official docs: "In the rare case that you'd like to get the raw socket response from the server". Can somebody help me to clarify, what are those case exactly? Shall I use raw-response for video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's one of those things when "if you have to ask, you don't need it".

You can and should deal with video and any byte-stream as illustrated in the link you provided:

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as fd:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
        fd.write(chunk)
```

`raw` attribute can be used, for instance, if you want to access server's response before any decoding, such as content decompression . For example when you send a request and specify `Content-Encoding: gzip`.

Comment: Ok, I see. For what data can I use 'content' in this case? E. g. is it ok for jpeg and other graphics file formats?

Comment: Generally speaking, `content` is essential for everything binary, and `text` is OK when you want a decoded HTML as a string.